# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 on NVMe SSD and using SATA SSD for storage

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, ssd, trim

I'm building a deep learning desktop and will be using Ubuntu 18.04. I currently have a Crucial MX500 2TB SATA SSD. I may get a Samsung 970 NVMe SSD to install the system on for faster loading (if this will not help much for Ubuntu 18.04 please let me know). How do I install the system on the NVMe SSD and how do I use the SATA SSD for storage? Also, how does trimming play a role in this?

Answer (score 2):

I think how you use your disk is a question of personal taste.

For easier ways, you can
1. Just install Ubuntu on nvme and mount SATA SSD somewhere you can use
or
2. Customization your partitions, create efi(500MB), /boot(500MB), root partition(reset of the disk) on nvme, and use SATA SSD as /home.  I don't see any real differences.

As for trim, Ubuntu 18.04 runs fstrim on all mounted SSD every 7 days.  You can also run `sudo fstrim -av` by yourself.

Discard option is not recommended anymore nowadays because it often impacts realtime performance rather than helps it.